# Instantiating an OracleDate object

Tags: c#, oracle

So my code looks like -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;

namespace OraDateTest {
    public partial class _Default: System.Web.UI.Page {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            OracleDate testdate1 = new OracleDate();

            String newdate = String.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yy}", DateTime.Parse("1/1/2001"));
            OracleDate testdate2 = new OracleDate(newdate);
        }
    }
}
```

testdate1 is instantiated just fine.

However, testdate2 throws this error.

```
[DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'OraOps11w.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)]
   Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OpsDat.AllocValCtxFromData(Int32 year, Int32 month, Int32 day, Int32 hour, Int32 minute, Int32 second, OpoDatValCtx*& ctx) +0
   Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OpoDatCtx..ctor(Int32 year, Int32 month, Int32 day, Int32 hour, Int32 minute, Int32 second) +190
   Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleDate..ctor(Int32 year, Int32 month, Int32 day, Int32 hour, Int32 minute, Int32 second) +237
   Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleDate..cctor() +64

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleDate' threw an exception.]
   Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleDate..ctor(DateTime data) +23
   OraDateTest._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\users\jonesmi\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\OraDateTest\OraDateTest\Default.aspx.cs:14
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
```

If it truly couldn't find 'OraOps11w.dll', wouldn't I get an error on both instances? Is it possible that my dll is out of date?

Comment: can you try to upgrade to odp.net 11.2 and try to see if it works OR validate that you currently do have the files msvcr71.dll  & mfc71.dll that came with the Xcopy ODP.NET.

Comment: I am using ODP.net 11.2. Also I have msvcr71, version 7.10.3052.4, mfc71.dll, version 7.10.3077.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Unzip all the JAR's in zip file of odt.net you downloaded
Get all the files inside that you just unzipped:
    oci.dll (renamed from 'oci.dll.dbl')
    Oracle.DataAccess.dll
    oraociicus11.dll
    OraOps11w.dll
    orannzsbb11.dll
    oraocci11.dll
    ociw32.dll (renamed from 'ociw32.dll.dbl')
Copy all the dll files into the bin dir of your .net exe
```

Comment: I copied all of those dll's into my .exe folder and it still doesn't work.

Comment: try removing your reference from project and adding it again.  try also to put Oracle.DataAccess.dll in same bin dir as your others files stated above.

Comment: Do you have a standard Oracle client installed on the machine as well?

Comment: Yes, I have the Oracle Client installed.

Comment: ODP may be trying to use the actual Oracle Client instead.  I think oracle might have issues with having both installed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8277/discussion-between-duckmike-and-dmitry-savy)